# Responding to a switch to full-screen mode (AKA "theater mode") in the browser, with Javascript

Tags: javascript, resize, document, fullscreen, detect

On most browsers hitting F11 switches the browser into a mode where there are no toolbars and menus. I'd like to make adjustments to my page layout when the user goes into that mode (specifically - there's a DIV that should cover the entire client area - If the user F11s - then the extra space added to the bottom is uncovered by the big div).

I tried using onkeydown event and responding to the F11 keycode (122) - but it triggers BEFORE the mode switches (after the key is pressed) - wherein the clientHeight of the documentElement is still as it was before.

I also tried responding to document.onresize and document.documentElement.onresize both of which doesn't seem to trigger when going F11.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

window.onresize seems to work on both FF3 and IE8...

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 15, Firefox 10, and Safari 5.1 now provide APIs to programmatically trigger fullscreen mode. Fullscreen mode triggered this way provide events to detect fullscreen changes and CSS pseudo-classes for styling fullscreen elements. Note that these events/pseudo-classes do not appear to apply when the user hits F11 however.

See [this hacks.mozilla.org blog post](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/) for details.